# Turn a list of vectors into a list of matrices without a for loop

Tags: r, matrix, vector

If I have a list of vectors that I created using the following:

```
a <- list()
for (i in 1:10) a[[i]] <- c(i,1:5)
```

What is the best way (without using a for loop) to turn this into a list of matrices, one for each vector, each having ncol = 2?

Comment: `lapply(a, matrix, ncol = 2)` or `lapply(a, matrix, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)`? Your question is rather vague, since it's not clear what you expect the output to look like. A list with just one matrix would fit your current description `list(matrix(unlist(a), ncol=2))`

Comment: Thanks! that works

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness.  Yeah I meant for the list to be n matrices with n being the number of vectors in the original list.